# React setState keeps running before variable is initialised

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a function tied to a button click which updates the state. This src element in state is linked to an img component. However I have to click this button twice for the image to show up. I believe it's because setState is running before the setimg variable is fully loaded.

```
runThis(){
    var c = document.createElement("canvas")
    c.width = "450";
    c.height = "394"
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d")
    var newimg = document.createElement("img")
    newimg.src = this.props.location.url
    ctx.drawImage(newimg,10,10)
    var setimg = c.toDataURL("image/png")
    this.setState({
        src:setimg
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting state before image has finished loading. That might be causing problem. Apply onload event listener on image and setState when image has finished loading.

```js
runThis(){
    var newimg = document.createElement("img")
    newimg.onload = this.imageLoaded
    newimg.src = this.props.location.url
}

imageLoaded(e){
    var c = document.createElement("canvas")
    c.width = "450";
    c.height = "394"
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d")
    ctx.drawImage(e.target,10,10)
    this.setState({
          src:c.toDataURL("image/png")
     })
}
```

Please let me know if it does not help.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Also the `src:this.c.toDataURL("image/png")` should be `src:c.toDataURL("image/png")` as it's a local variable

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. I have made appropriate change as you suggested.

Comment: So for my image it is composed of 4 other images. For desktop it is loading the image fine, but for mobile it loads the image with only 2 other images at first, then  i press the button again and it loads the others one by one. So it takes 3 button clicks. Any idea why this might be happening specifically for mobile?

Comment: At every click, you are triggering some rerender which is causing the state to synchronise. It is hard to tell without looking at full code. Can you please create a sandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can shift `setState` into a callback function if the issue is indeed only it runs before context

---

```
   runThis({callback}){
      var c = document.createElement("canvas")
      c.width = "450";
      c.height = "394"
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d")
     var newimg = document.createElement("img")
     newimg.src = this.props.location.url
     ctx.drawImage(newimg,10,10)
     var setimg = c.toDataURL("image/png")
    callback(setimg)
    }

    //usage
    this.runThis({param=>this.setState({ src: param })})
```